# UITextField, text jumps down slightly when editing begins

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm having an odd issue here. I have UITextFields in my table cells. When I select the field the text jumps very slightly down:

[image]

The font is system default 17. I have `adjust to fit` turned on at size 17. I have tried turning off `adjust to fit` and there is still a jump. I have tried using different border styles and this also makes no difference. I have tried turning off clip to bounds, it still jumps. I have also tried making the frame taller (much taller) and it still jumps. The only thing that works is if I make the font size much smaller eg 13. What am I doing wrong here? If I can make the font smaller to fix the jump then why doesn't making the frame bigger work? Any pointers on this would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think it is issue with the height of textfield. Please increase some height of textfield then check.

Comment: I did that. I doubled the height of its frame and it still jumps

Comment: can u provide your whole code of textfield delegate?

Comment: Are you using library for it? or it is default iphone keyboard ? @KexAri

Comment: Will you send me your demo because I haven't got issue like that. i build new demo for it and everything just working fine. and please check that it is not xcode version issue. Which xcode version you're using ?

Comment: @JeckyModi These are UITextFields with no library. Version I have is iOS 10

Comment: Can you share a sample project that reproduces it?

Comment: Not a real solution, but changing the font (eg. using Arial) does remove the jumping issue. I am on iOS 10.2

Answer (score 11):

I must admit that I've always seen this little bouncing during my developments but I never investigate around it.
Some points that I've used to replicate your issue:

1. **two textfields** with default dimensions and settings
2. using system default font and change it's size **from 13 to 25** just to
   test the behavior

I suppose there are more other ways to solve your problem but I don't find a fast property to stop this little "jumping" of text. I've decide to analize the current `UITextField` (*$ xcrun swift -version = Swift 3.1*) to see it's composition:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTextField.delegate = self
    }
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("\ntextFieldDidBeginEditing")
        showLayersDescription()
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("\ntextFieldDidEndEditing")
        showLayersDescription()
    }
    func showLayersDescription() {
        myTextField.layer.sublayers?.forEach{ print($0.debugDescription)}
    }
}
```

where `myTextField` is essentially one of the two textfields

**Output using font size 17**:

[image]

Essentially seems there are **3** `CALayer`:

- a layer with frame = `CGRect (0 0; 252 30)` that have
  `_UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundViewNeue` as delegate that have the same dimension of our textfield
- a layer with frame = `CGRect (7 2; 238 26)` that is showed only in our
  `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and it have `UIFieldEditor` as delegate
  that seems to be the responsible for the editing part..
- a layer that appear only in `textFieldDidEndEditing` with frame = `CGRect.zero` and with delegate `UITextFieldLabel`

If I write something to the first textField then I go to the next textfield nothing happened BUT if I return to the first textField and then to the second **the layer with frame equal to `CGRect.zero` change to frame = `CGRect(7 0.5; 238 27.5)`**

This is **the little height (0.5)** that we can see during the beginning and the ending of our editing.

We can try to refine the debug and intercept these layers with an extension:

```
extension UITextField
{
    func debugLayers() {
        print("We have the follow layers:")
        let FieldEditor: AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("UIFieldEditor")!
        let LabelLayer: AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("_UILabelLayer")!
        let TextFieldRoundRect: AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("_UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundViewNeue")!
        self.layer.sublayers?.forEach{
            if ($0.delegate?.self.isKind(of: TextFieldRoundRect))! { print("- layer with _UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundViewNeue as delegate have frame:\($0.frame)") }
            if ($0.delegate?.self.isKind(of: FieldEditor))! { print("- layer with UIFieldEditor as delegate have frame:\($0.frame)") }
            if $0.self.isKind(of: LabelLayer) { print("- layer is kind of _UILabelLayer have frame:\($0.frame)") }
        }
    }
}
```

So we have for example:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTextField.delegate = self
    }
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("\ntextFieldDidBeginEditing")
        myTextField.debugLayers()
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("\ntextFieldDidEndEditing")
        myTextField.debugLayers()
    }
}
```

**Output always with font size 17:**

[image]

As we can see we have always this **0.5 difference in height** in that layer..

Making other tries I've seen that this behaviour **happened only if the default size is between 13 and 17**, under 13 and from 18 to 25 this not happened has you've report to your question.

### A solution:

I think the best way to intercept and trying to correct this one it's to make a new extension:

```
extension UITextField
{
    override open func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let FieldEditor: AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("UIFieldEditor")!
        let LabelLayer: AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("_UILabelLayer")!
        self.layer.sublayers?.forEach{
            if ($0.delegate?.self.isKind(of: FieldEditor))! {
                var f = $0.frame
                f.origin.y = 0.0
                $0.frame = f
            }
            if $0.self.isKind(of: LabelLayer) {
                var layerFrame = CGRect.zero
                layerFrame.origin = self.editingRect(forBounds: self.bounds).origin
                layerFrame.size = self.editingRect(forBounds: self.bounds).size
                if let size = self.font?.pointSize, 14 ... 17 ~= size {
                    layerFrame.origin.y = -0.5
                } else {
                    layerFrame.origin.y = 0.0
                }
                $0.frame = layerFrame
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Final considerations:

**This extension suppress the little "jumping down" of the text** during the change to another textField. This is probably to balance the :

```
contentsCenter = CGRect (0.485 0.485; 0.000588235 0.000588235)
```

that both the second and third layer have with this group of font sizes.
As you see in the extension I've set to zero also the height origin of the layer with `UIFieldEditor` delegate (that before have 2.0 as height) because it's involved to this change, I've maded it to balance the constraints differences.

### Update for a valid and approved extension:

I've read your comment so I've analyzed in deep the situation about layers: what I've found is that the layer who have the gap of -0.5 height **NEVER** present sublayers, when the other **ALWAYS** present one sublayer ( have `UIFieldEditor` as delegate) so we can easily correct the extension as:

```
extension UITextField
{
    override open func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.sublayers?.forEach{
            if let subs = $0.sublayers, subs.count>0 {
                var f = $0.frame
                f.origin.y = 0.0
                $0.frame = f
            } else {
                var layerFrame = CGRect.zero
                layerFrame.origin = self.editingRect(forBounds: self.bounds).origin
                layerFrame.size = self.editingRect(forBounds: self.bounds).size
                if let size = self.font?.pointSize, 14 ... 17 ~= size {
                    layerFrame.origin.y = -0.5
                } else {
                    layerFrame.origin.y = 0.0
                }
                $0.frame = layerFrame
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested this new extension and it behaves correctly like the old one.

Comment: A **GitHUB repo** with this code [here](https://github.com/aornano/UITextField-like-to-jump) to make your tests..

Comment: I will test this solution soon, but from a quick glance, I'm curious if it would be rejected from the App Store for these lines: "let FieldEditor: AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("UIFieldEditor")!
        let LabelLayer: AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("_UILabelLayer")!"

Comment: @David This is a good observation, I've update and test the extension, look at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

So you may have stumbled on something very strange. If you subclass your UITextField to something like this.

```
class NonJumpyTextField: UITextField {

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var previousRect = super.textRect(forBounds: bounds)

        print("Bounds: \(bounds)")
        print("TextRect: \(previousRect)")
        print("TextFieldRect \(frame)")

        //not reccomended but does seem to help
        previousRect.origin.y = 2.25

        return previousRect
    }
}
```

and read the logs you get some odd behavior when editing it prints

```
Bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)
TextRect: (7.0, 2.0, 86.0, 96.0)
TextFieldRect (64.0, 66.0, 97.0, 30.0)
Bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 97.0, 30.0)
TextRect: (7.0, 2.0, 83.0, 26.0)
TextFieldRect (64.0, 66.0, 97.0, 30.0)
Bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)
TextRect: (7.0, 2.0, 86.0, 96.0)
TextFieldRect (64.0, 66.0, 97.0, 30.0)
```

when done editing

```
Bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 97.0, 30.0)
TextRect: (7.0, 2.0, 83.0, 26.0)
TextFieldRect (64.0, 66.0, 97.0, 30.0)
Bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)
TextRect: (7.0, 2.0, 86.0, 96.0)
TextFieldRect (64.0, 66.0, 97.0, 30.0)
```

In the sample I was working with brute forcing the y position did help but not really recommended. I suspect the issue has to do with the bounds being a seemingly random 100 x 100. Hopefully something here will help you find a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the `contentVerticalAlignment` property of UITextField can lead to this wierd behavior.

You can add a symbolic breakpoint

> [UITextField  setContentVerticalAlignment:]

to checkout  if you  change the `contentVerticalAlignment` property of 
UITextField accidentally.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to increase the height of inputView in UITextField.

UITextField has inputView that will present when object becomes first responder.

Comment: how would I increase that?